# Pandas, mulitindexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, multi-index

I have data that I need to aggregate for per column and then per column again. What I need is total spend per product category for each unique customer. Multiindex should do this. Problem is that I am new to Pandas, and I don't understand multiindexing.

I have data structured like this:

```
 Customer  Products  Amount
1  001       Toys      5
2  002       Toys      6
3  002       Cars      7
4  001       Toys      2
5  001       Cars      9
```

I need it like this:

```
Customers Products      Sum of ammount
001       Toys          7
          Cars          9
002       Toys          6
          Cars          7
```

Later I need to transform it so that I can get total spend per product category, per customer.

```
Customer Toys Cars
001      7    9
002      6    7
```

I have been playing around with the code, but I am stuck. Have been reading up, but not finding exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Customer','Products'])['Amount'].sum().reset_index(name='Sum of ammount')
print (df1)
  Customer Products  Sum of ammount
0      001     Cars               9
1      001     Toys               7
2      002     Cars               7
3      002     Toys               6
```

Then you can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) from `df1`:

```
print (df1.pivot(index='Customer',columns='Products',values='Sum of ammount'))
Products  Cars  Toys
Customer            
001          9     7
002          7     6
```

If need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) from `df`:

```
print (df.pivot_table(index='Customer',columns='Products',values='Amount', aggfunc=sum))
Products  Cars  Toys
Customer            
001          9     7
002          7     6
```

EDIT:

For nicer `df` you can [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (df.pivot_table(index='Customer',columns='Products',values='Amount', aggfunc=sum)
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

  Customer  Cars  Toys
0      001     9     7
1      002     7     6

print (df1.pivot(index='Customer',columns='Products',values='Sum of ammount')
          .reset_index()
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

  Customer  Cars  Toys
0      001     9     7
1      002     7     6
```

Comment: Thank you Jezrael. I will eventually do this on 30 million rows and I am worried about RAM with pivot. I have 32 GB available. How efficient is pivoting?

Comment: Phhhooo, hard question, but `pivot` is very difficult and memory consumed operation. But you can try it.

Comment: And I am very curious how it works with your large `DataFrame`.

Comment: The input you provided worked perfect on a small sample. I added a fillna(0). I will now attempt to run the script on the full dataset. Will let you know. Thank you Jazreal.

Comment: It ran on about 15 min, reading 33M rows. Unique customer ids was about 2M. Number of unique products groups was 12. These formed the new columns. Compared to other tranformations I have done, this is below average. Of total 32GB RAM, it used only about half when performing the operations.